# Using an array as a parameter to compare to using countif

Tags: google-sheets, countif

I have this issue I haven't been able to work out.
I have several teams with a lot of members. Each member uploads a lead to a system that has another column that writes down when the lead took to a proposal. I need to count how many leads did the team upload that actually took to a proposal.

It looks something like this (simplified):

[image: Data]

I want to count how many leads uploaded from mauricio's team actually have a date under proposal date. I tried doing something like this but the `if` stayed at the first cell (in this case "mauricio@trial").

[image: trial formula]

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$8:$C$19="")*($D$8:$D$19=A1))+SUMPRODUCT(($C$8:$C$19="")*($D$8:$D$19=B1))+SUMPRODUCT(($C$8:$C$19="")*($D$8:$D$19=B2))+SUMPRODUCT(($C$8:$C$19="")*($D$8:$D$19=B3))
```

Basically I did it with a two criteria count for each one of the team members then added them together.  The formula for one team member for easier reading is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$8:$C$19="")*($D$8:$D$19=A1))
```

the part in between the brackets making a logical comparison is your criteria for your matching.  The * acts the same as an AND statement.  Since you need to know for this member OR this member you need a SUMPRODUCT (or other formula) for each member add them together to get your over all results

Comment: That works, the problem is that I have around 95 teams so that's not efficient in the long run hehe. I tried another thing in which I first use a filter and then try to do the array stuff but doesn't work. 
I first filter the database to get all the members on one team and then try to use the other conditions:

=COUNTIFS(Sheet12!N:N,filter(Auxiliar!B:B,Auxiliar!C:C=A8,Auxiliar!F:F>0),Sheet12!F:F,"")

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array, but the result will be an array; and also multidimensional vectors are difficult to handle.

So I split the two columns for the team leader and members and added them together:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(E48:E59,B41:B43,D48:D59,"<>"))+COUNTIFS(E48:E59,A41,D48:D59,"<>")
```

Since the first COUNTIFS returns an array, the items must be added; and also the formula should be entered as an array formula, by holding down `ctrl+shift` while hitting `enter`.  If you do that correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula in the formula bar.

Comment: That works, the problem is that I have around 95 teams so that's not efficient in the long run hehe. I tried another thing in which I first use a filter and then try to do the array stuff but doesn't work. 
I first filter the database to get all the members on one team and then try to use the other conditions:

=COUNTIFS(Sheet12!N:N,filter(Auxiliar!B:B,Auxiliar!C:C=A8,Auxiliar!F:F>0),Sheet12!F:F,"")

Comment: @MauricioBarrera So your stated problem does not really reflect the true scope of what you are trying to solve. That makes things more difficult.  Why not just add a fourth column to your lower table listing the team for each line; then you could easily use a filter, or pivot table, or maybe even use the `AGGREGATE` function.